# Apache sites-enable

Tags: linux, apache

Why in sites-enable the file name is 000-default but not default as in sites-aviable?

Answer (score 1):

This ensures the `000-default` file is loaded before the others. Otherwise, a file named `a.com` would become the default for unknown virtualhosts instead of `default`.